# Regular expression to split line separated by tab

Tags: regex

I have a file containing many lines of the following

line    123456  89  2018-02-12 14:47:07 +0000   here
line    234567  90  2019-02-13 09:02:01 +0000   there

So I would like to split them into the last four parts from each line

Here is the regular expresion that 
"\t\d{6}\t\d{2}\t\w+"

It gives out

123456\t89\t2018
234567\t90\t2019

How do I update the regular expression to get

123456\t89\t2018-02-12 14:47:07\there
234567\t90\t2019-02-13 09:02:01\tthere

instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `str.split`?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Yes - in fact, this might be more efficient in this case. Since this file has simple uniform delimiters, it's worth to consider if the complexity of a regex is really justified here. A regex might help, however, to parse the date/time items into their components.

Comment: Yep, I have my fair share of regular expressions (heck I have a module on pypi thats basically regex on steroids), but this isn't the case that benefits from regex. As for the datetime parts, forget regex, the datetime module as a handy feature for that [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: `datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` should do the trick.

Comment: And, btw, as far as efficiency goes. Unless you're going to the million line files, its probably best to neglect efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

The end of your regex `"\t\d{6}\t\d{2}\t\w+"` matches up to the next non-word character, which happens to be the dash after the year item. To capture the remaining characters, I'd recommend a negative character class, which matches everything except `\t`. That is:

```
"\t\d{6}\t\d{2}\t[^\t]+\t\w+"
```

Usually, this is easier than positively stating all possible characters that might occur.

Comment: @user2029709 Glad to help! Please consider marking my posting as the accepted answer. Thanks!